# How to import com.google.inject.Singleton?

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

I am learning Gin with [GinTutorial](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial) and I've stacked on silly problem.

In `bind(MyWidgetMainPanel.class).in(Singleton.class);` Singleton does not exist.

I've already tried the following:

`import com.google.gwt.inject.client.AbstractGinModule;
 import com.google.gwt.inject.client.Singleton;
 import com.google.gwt.inject.Singleton;`

IDE shows that Singleton does not exist before compilation time.

If I try to use `import com.google.inject.Singleton;` it shows that Singleton does not exist on compilation.

- gin-2.1.2
- gwt2.6

I'd be happy to have any of your ideas or explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that it is not enough to add `gin-2.1.2.jar` to classpath. It requires `guice-3.0.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the solution, but when I use injection like this with GIN in GWT, I do not import `com.google.gwt.inject.Singleton` in my GinModule, but `com.google.inject.Singleton` and it works. 
I hope it helps.